# How can I read __DATA__ into an array so that each word gets its own index?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to print the strings `white` and `acer` with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
@a=<DATA>;
print "$a[9] $a[14]";

__DATA__
one two three four five six seven
black yellow white green
apple orange 
hp acer samsung
```

How can I read `__DATA__` into an array so that `white` is at index 9 and `acer` is at index 14?

Comment: You mean, aside from using the `.` concatenation operator?  Consider `print $a[9] . " " . $a[14] . "\n";` or even `print join(' ', @a[9,14]);`.  Note that the way you have written it will also work, provided indices 9 and 14 are defined.

Answer (score 4):

if you inspect your *"array"* with [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html), you will see that it only has four elements, thus indexes '9' and '14' are not defined:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @a = <DATA>;

print Dumper \@a;

# prints 
#[
#          'one two three four five six seven
#',
#          'black yellow white green
#',
#          'apple orange 
#',
#          'hp acer samsung 
#'
#]

__DATA__
one two three four five six seven
black yellow white green
apple orange 
hp acer samsung
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want each word to take occupy an element of your array, you need to process the individual lines.

The [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function splits (on whitespace by default) strings into a  list of strings:

```
my @a = map +split, <DATA>;
print $a[9], "\n";  # 'white'
print $a[14], "\n"; # 'acer'
```

Comment: You probably want to add a little explanation about `+split`, this may look quite strange to people who are not so familiar with Perl syntax.

Comment: @zaid why use `+` for `map + split` without `+` also works like `map split`

Answer (score 3):

First, *always* `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of each script.  These pragmas will help you avert problems in your script.  Also, use lexical variables, i.e., those you declare by using `my`.

As mentioned, one way to achieve your results is to iterate through all of your `DATA` lines, `split`ting each into `@a`.  Here's one quite common way to do this (as you would typically do with files):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a;
while (<DATA>) {
    push @a, split;
}

print "$a[9] $a[14]"; # Prints white acer

__DATA__
one two three four five six seven
black yellow white green
apple orange 
hp acer samsung
```

Note that `split` doesn't have any explicit parameters.  In this case, it's equivalent to `split ' ', $_`, i.e., lines in the default scalar `$_` are `split` on whitespace.

Another way is to 'slurp' all of your data in a single chunk, and then `split` the contents of that read:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
my @a = split ' ', <DATA>;
print "$a[9] $a[14]"; # Prints white acer

__DATA__
one two three four five six seven
black yellow white green
apple orange 
hp acer samsung
```

The `local $/;` line lets you read all of the data at once.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

While slurping (as in `my @a = <DATA>` or `my @a = map +split, <DATA>`) seems OK for short files, you are better off reading line-by-line to make the memory footprint of your program proportional to the largest input line rather than the size of the file.

If you are going to slurp, it is better to read the file in as a single string as in the second part of [Kenosis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22204777/100754). The first part of that answer is what you should use.

An alternative to `split` without arguments is to use a capturing pattern to keep only sequences of non-space characters as in:

```
my @words;
push @words, /(\S+)/g while <DATA>;
```

In list context, `/(\S+)/g` will return all sequences of non-space characters in a line. Without an explicit binding, it matches on `$_` which is populated line by line from `DATA`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @words;
push @words, /(\S+)/g while <DATA>;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@words;

__DATA__
one two three four five six seven
black yellow white green
apple orange
hp acer samsung
```

Output:

```
VAR1 = [
          'one',
          'two',
          'three',
          'four',
          'five',
          'six',
          'seven',
          'black',
          'yellow',
          'white',
          'green',
          'apple',
          'orange',
          'hp',
          'acer',
          'samsung'
        ];
```

Now, while the

```
push @words, /(\S+)/g while <DATA>;
```

line looks neat, it does create a temporary list for each line. If you have lines with lots of fields, you may be able to save some memory overhead with an explicit loop (which is something you can't do with `split`):

```
my @words;

while (<DATA>) {
    while (/(\S+)/g) {
        push @words, $1;
    }
}
```

However, my default choice, in the absence of evidence of the benefits of some other alternative, would be to go with Kenosis' recommendation:

```
push @words, split while <DATA>;
```